# Spring OAuth in Google App Engine fails

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, oauth, spring-security

I am trying to implement OAuth1.0 using spring security like this :

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public RestOperations twitterOAuthRestTemplate() {
    return new OAuthRestTemplate(twitterOAuthDetails());
}
```

But it fails at runtime with :

```
jjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.ProxySelector is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
at org.springframework.security.oauth.consumer.client.CoreOAuthConsumerSupport.<init>(CoreOAuthConsumerSupport.java:64)
at org.springframework.security.oauth.consumer.client.OAuthRestTemplate.<init>(OAuthRestTemplate.java:17)
at org.springframework.security.oauth.consumer.client.OAuthRestTemplate.<init>(OAuthRestTemplate.java:20)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find anything better than create own copies of Spring classes (OAuthRestTemplate, CoreOAuthConsumerSupport) and get rid of ProxySelector.